# SerialPort reading problems

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have to create an aplication which reads the registers from a PLC every 200ms. To do that I am using something like:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 21;
   timer1.Interval = 200;
   timer1.Start();
}

private void ProcessTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (dataReceived)
   {
        dataReceived = false;
        port.Read(buffer_rx, 0, 21);
        TranslateValues();
   }

   if (port.IsOpen && connectected)
   {  
      // sends command for a new reading
      port.Write(buffer_tx, 0, length);
   }
}

private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   Invoke(new EventHandler(DoUpdate));
}

void DoUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dataReceived = true;
}
```

The problem is that my application freezes from time to time. When I debug this, the debugger points me to port.Read(), but doesn't throw any exceptions.

I have tried using a try-catch block but nothing was caught, and also made `time1.Interval = 2000`, but it didn't work either.

My question is, why is my application freezing at port.Read(), but not catching any exceptions? How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems you are trying to read data when there are none available.

Comment: I am reading data only if DataRecieved event fires so I don't understand how could there be no data if the event fires?

Comment: But the way you are doing it, is hardly synchronized. Loose the timer, and just do the reading in `DataReceived` event.

Comment: You are not paying attention to e.EventType in the DataReceived event handler.  Using ReceivedBytesThreshold (cold??) is also a pretty fundamental weakness.

Comment: And what should I use instead of RecievedBytesThreshold?